# I want to add the font settings to my edittext

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog, android-fonts

I want to add text on the image. for that I want to add font settings to my text. like add color, font styles etc..
. Can any one share the code.

I want exactly this kind of layout with source code:
[image: I want exactly this kind of layout with source code]

Comment: If you want layout with source code, hire a developer from [upwork](https://www.upwork.com/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read about [good examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Framelayout** to overlap views
or you can use a **CardView** as well.

Comment: I can create layout(UI). I want code to get fonts and it's styles and color.